# Match all the instances of [ ... ] in java using pattern.matcher

Tags: java, regex

What is the correct way to match all the instances of [ ] in a string.

I'm trying with

```
String content = "ZZZ AA PP [AA] Q[QQ] AAA ZZ";

  String string = "\\[.*\\]";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(string);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
```

It matches from [AA] Q[QQ] as a single instance whereas I want to get both the instances between [].

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `String string = "\\[[^\\]]*\\]";` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try making the regex non-greedy by using this:

```
String content = "ZZZ AA PP [AA] Q[QQ] AAA ZZ";
String string = "(\\[.*?\\])";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(string);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

int count = 0;
while (matcher.find())
    count++;

System.out.println("Found " + count + " matches.");
```

**Output:**

```
Found 2 matches.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex

```
\[.*?\]
```

It uses the [lazy mode](http://javascript.info/tutorial/greedy-and-lazy#lazy-mode) of the quantifier instead of the greedy mode. (Greedy mode is used by default)

> The lazy mode of quantifiers is a counterpart to greedy. It can be enabled by putting a question mark '?' after the quantifier, so it becomes ? or +? or even ?? for '?'.

What it is doing:

> In lazy mode the engine tries to repeat as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It matches `[AA] Q[QQ]` because all regex patterns are greedy by default, trying to match the biggest groups they can. So when it sees the first `]` it goes on to see if it can make the group even bigger.

There are two ways of doing what you want. One is using a reluctant quantifier `\\[.*?\\]`. The other is capturing everything, except the right-side bracket `\\[[^\\]]*\\]`.